# Average a dimension of a chunk (xarray)

Tags: python-xarray

Let X be a variable I have stored in multiple files. In each files, X has dimension of (time, depth, latitude, longitude). I wish to do a yearly average, and each file store a year of data.

To be efficient, I open the data with `X = xarray.open_mfdataset('path'+'year_*_X.nc')`.

I do not want to average all the time axis, i.e.: `X.mean(dim='time')`.

I observe that X store 'chunks' since it gives the 'chunksize', so maybe it can be used to average the time dimension of each chunks?

`In [1] : X`

`Out[1] : <xarray.DataArray 'ty_trans_submeso' (time: 240, st_ocean: 50, yu_ocean: 200, xt_ocean: 360)>
dask.array<shape=(240, 50, 200, 360), dtype=float32, chunksize=(12, 50, 200, 360)>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X.groupby('time.year').mean(dim='time')` should do the trick as long as `time` is a datetime64 object.